# Which were the first 500 apps on the App Store when it launched in 2008?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore

The subject says it all. Is there somewhere a list of the first set of apps on the iPhone App Store when it went live in July 2008?

Comment: May I ask why you want this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PinchMedia RSS feed in Wayback Machine is the best I could get so far:

[Top 100 Paid Apps as of July 21, 2008](http://web.archive.org/web/20080721054229/http://feeds.feedburner.com/Top100PaidIphoneApplications-PinchMedia)

Still hoping I can get a full list. According to [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2008/07/10/app-store-launches-upgrade-itunes-now/), there were 552 apps at the beginning, 417 paid, 135 free. If there would be a way to get top lists for all the categories, it should be possible to assemble the full list.

Answer (score 1):

The closest reference I found is this [article](http://techcrunch.com/2008/07/10/iphone-app-store-the-early-list-of-top-downloads/) from TechCrunch (not my favorite site, BTW!) on the top downloads after launch. Not as a comprehensive list as what you're looking for (first 500). Have you tried searching the Way Back Machine on review sites such as Macworld? You may find more articles from that original launch week and sort of compile a list of your own.

Hope this helps.

Comment: See my answer with my preliminary results. Hope we're getting there…

Answer (score -2):

i read from a article very recently, and thef first app presented is super monkey ball from sega.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on this, such as naming the article or the newspaper/magazine/website you read it on. Perhaps a link if you have it. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.